# Using Xdebug with PhpDesigner

Tags: xdebug, phpdesigner

I want to use Xdebug tool for profiling code execution speed, memory usage of my php application.

My application frame work is codeigniter and IDE is PhpDesigner.

i followed the instruction in phpDesigner manual [PhpDesigner xdebug configuration](http://wiki.mpsoftware.dk/doku.php/tutorials/configure_xampp_with_xdebug_and_get_it_working_in_phpdesigner_7)

But when i debug using debug option f9 in PhpDesigner menu it shows Php5.dll file is missing.

How to debug my php script using xdebug and phpDesigner

Answer (score 1):

I'm using external debugging for projects on my local server.
To debug file you just need to open it in IDE and run script from browser.

Look at this tutorial http://wiki.mpsoftware.dk/doku.php/tutorials/debug_php_scripts_from_your_browser_with_phpdesigner_7_external_debugging